# What is the order of listing files and directories with Linux ls?

Tags: linux, ls

In my current directory I have directories a, b, and c, and files d and e. The man page for ls suggests that entries are sorted alphabetically which is true for

```
$ ls -d *
a  b  c  d  e
```

but not for

```
$ ls *
d  e

a:
1  2

b:
3  4

c:
5  6
```

Why doesn't `ls *` also sort alphabetically rather than separating files and directories? Is this distinction made clear in the man page?

Comment: The sorting is being done by the shell expanding the wildcard, not `ls`.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: When you use the `-d` option it doesn't need to distinguish files and directories. So it just lists everything in the order it was given. Without the `-d` option, it lists the contents of directories, and it does that separately from listing files.

Answer (score 0):

[Maybe this will help](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-list-files-in-linux-using-the-ls-command/)

The answer is that it does put them in alphabetical order but it separates files & directories.  When you use '*' your passing a list of all files & directories in the location to get lists of all sub files/directories.  It can put all the files in the normal block table to fit the screen but with directories it needs to put sub-files under each one for clarity on what sub file belongs to each.